Inheritance and Visibility in Swift
I'm confused about the content in the swift doc:

Notice that the initializer for the EquilateralTriangle class has three different steps:

Setting the value of properties that the subclass declares.
Calling the superclass’s initializer.
Changing the value of properties defined by the superclass. Any additional setup work that uses methods, getters, or setters can also be done at this point.


And then I try the example below in Swift and C++:
Swift
class Base {
    init() {
        print("Enter Base");
        setUp();
        print("Leave Base");
    }
    func setUp() -> Void {
        print("base setUp()")
    }
}

class Derived: Base {  
    let number: Int;
    override init () {      
        number = 5;
    }
    override func setUp() -> Void {
        print("derived setUp() \(number)")
    }
}

let d = Derived()
let b = Base()

Enter Base
derived setUp() 5
Leave Base
Enter Base
base setUp()
Leave Base

C++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Enter Base" << std::endl;
        setUp();
        std::cout << "Leave Base" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void setUp() {
        std::cout << "base setUp()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base {  
    int number;
public:
    Derived () {
        number = 5;
    }
    void setUp() override {
        std::cout << "derived setUp() " << number << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Derived d = Derived();
  Base b = Base();
}

Enter Base
base setUp()
Leave Base
Enter Base
base setUp()
Leave Base

Based on the two outputs above, it is evident that there are differences between C++ and Swift in terms of their inheritance philosophy. Could someone explain why the behavior differs between the two languages (Why does Swift allow a superclass to access subclass methods)?
I've already know the vtable in C++ and its mechanism, but I know nothing about Swift, so it would be nice if you could compare the difference of the underlying implementation between two languages.

You're doing different things in these code snippets...in Swift, you're creating one Base and one Derived; in C++, you're creating two Derived objects. I think the thing that's tripping you up is C++'s static typing.

I apologize for the mistake. I've edited it to one Base and one Derived. Based on my understanding, C++ sets up the superclass first and then handles the subclass memory, layer by layer, from the inside out. I am wondering if Swift follows the same approach, or if my understanding of C++ is incorrect?

Where did Swift allow the superclass to access the base subclass methods? You created an instance of Derived. Derived overrides setup, so the appropriate setup was called - Just because you called it in the inherited init doesn't change that.  If anything, I would say that C++ is giving the wrong output.

Note that in C++ base classes are fully initialized before any portion of the derived class gets initialized.  If Base() were to call Derived::setUp number would be uninitialized.

In C++, the base class is fully initialised before the derived class is. Calling the superclass constructor is one of the first things that the derived class constructor does. This means that if you were to call the derived class's setUp in the base class constructor, setUp would observe an uninitialised number. This is undesirable, because whoever wrote setUp might be assuming that all the fields are initialised (though this is less likely to happen when the method is called setUp). Therefore, virtual method calls in a constructor are designed to be dispatched statically. See also this post for more details.
On the other hand, Swift initialises the classes in the opposite order. Derived classes are initialised first. super.init can only be called after you have initialised all the stored properties that are declared in the derived class.
class Derived: Base {  
    let number: Int

    override init() {
        // super.init() // calling this here is not allowed!    
        number = 5
        super.init() // calling it here is ok :)
    }
}

Therefore, it is safe to call virtual methods in the base class initialiser. By the time it is called, all the derived class stored properties are guaranteed to be initialised.
See also: Two-Phase Initialization in the language guide.

The phrase “Swift initializes the classes in the opposite order” is exactly what I needed, thanks! Is there any material explaining why the Swift team decided to approach inheritance this way? It’s so different from what I learned in C++.

@ChenSam You can probably find something of the sort by searching on forums.swift.org. It's just one of many ways to solve the problem of "calling virtual methods in a base class constructor". C++ solves this by dispatching everything statically. Swift solves this by initialising derived classes first. Others like Java doesn't solve this at all :) This might also be helpful.

Sure! thanks mate.

@ChenSam Apple's published book The Swift Programming Language has a whole section explaining why initialisation is as it is. See the section of Two Phase Initialisation.
